# jquery how to select <option> using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove the years 2014 & 2015 from both the check in and check out using Regex-

[image]

I tried using containsRegex but I guess I'm doing something wrong:

```
$("option:containsRegex(/^((2014)|(2015))$/)").remove();
```

Here's the example code:

```
<select name="check_in" class="required">
    <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>  
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="check_out" class="required">
    <option value="">Year</option>  
        <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>  
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>   
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

I can do it like that:

```
$('option:contains("2014")').remove();
$('option:contains("2015")').remove();
```

But I want to be able to do it using regex becuase the real file is more complicated than that..
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJjGb/1/ so you can try.

To sum it up I want to remove certain 'option's of the 'select' element.
and to be able to choose which option by using regex-
In this example removing option '2014' and '2015' using regex from both check in and check out.
Thank you.
(Here I did that without regex: http://jsfiddle.net/PJjGb/)

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/580951).

Comment: If you know exactly what to remove, why would you want to use regex. Or you can clarify your question more.

Comment: @Romoku He is not parsing HTML though, just the inner text of the option element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you need a regex, but here it is :

```
$('option').filter(function() {
    return /(2014|2015)/.test(this.value);
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PJjGb/2/)

Comment: Not that it matters, but since the OP is using `:contains()`, I'm thinking they want to test against `$(this).text()`, not `this.value` (although the same in their code). It's up to them; your answer demonstrates how to filter dynamically, and with a regex

Comment: @adeneo ye it works, Thank you.
Do any of you maybe know how to make it work using containsRegex?
Like I have seen here: http://bit.ly/1bJkLaE

Comment: @Ian - agreed, `contains()` would equal a regex test on the textContent, but `this.value` seemed easier to write as it's the same thing in the code in the question. If the text is really what the OP wants, it's easy to change.

Comment: @BooyaRin Might I suggest you test your regex expressions at http://regexpal.com/. It's a quick and easy way to make sure you Regex expressions are getting to what you want. Otherwise, you might also look at the CSS Selectors link in my answer, tho i'll prolly delete it soon, since everyone seems to think i ddn't answer your question.

Comment: @SpYk3HH The regexpal.com I'm familiar with. The CSS Selector link was usefull, Ty.

Comment: `Not sure why you need a regex` Isn't it better for your digestion? +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

The regex itself should be as simple as `/(2014|2015)/`

---

Why use the regex when it's just a simple jQuery call using simple css, like so:

```
$('option[value*=2014], option[value*=2015]').remove();
```

## Example

---

Learn more about [CSS Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

- [attribute*=value]: attribute contains value
- [attribute^=value]: attribute begins with value
- [attribute$=value]: attribute ends with value
- [attribute~=value]: attribute is within space separated list
- [attribute|=value]: attribute is within dash separated list

---

Or as also suggested by [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813554/jquery-how-to-select-option-using-regex#answer-17813639), if you insist on RegEx, you could use jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$('option').filter(function(i) { return /(2014|2015)/.test(this.value); }).remove();
```

## Example

---

---

**|OR|** If you're wanting to test against the text:

```
$('option:contains(2014), option:contains(2015)').remove();
```

## Example

*|OR|* using `.filter()`

```
$('option').filter(function(i) { return /(2014|2015)/.test($(this).text()); }).remove();
```

## Example

---

---

***|OR|*** For a **Full Combo** testing against *TEXT* && *VALUE*, I would suggest using the `.filter()` method agian, with a `||` statement:

```
$('option').filter(function(i) { return /(2014|2015)/.test(this.value) || /(2014|2015)/.test($(this).text()); }).remove();
```

## EXAMPLE

Comment: From the Question..."becuase the real file is more complicated than that"

Comment: The value property and value attribute are not the same thing

Comment: @Esailija if the value prop is changed after DOM load, sure, otherwise they will return the same value every time.

Comment: Downvoting of this severity (-3 as I write) is inappropriate.  The questioner certainly asks for a regex, but actually the use of modifier symbols for attribute = value was something I had not heard of and is appropriate for the question: just because the questioner asks for one thing doesn't mean you shouldn't tell them about an equally good/better/simpler way of doing what they want.